# Using wsdl file Fedex Asp.net Website in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, wsdl, fedex

I'm trying use the Fedex file wsdl for shipping services but when I try to use that resource (file) in the webserver, I receive an error message that the URL is incorrect and I try test the URL in the Browser and I have a error 404 Not Found.

When I tested locally using  the local path in localhost for the Web Reference and work fine. But when I upload to Azure this not work.
Any Suggestions???
Thanks

Comment: show us some code plz - and your web.config

Comment: I use locally the wsdl file locally and work fine but I need how use in the asp.net Website hosted on Azure. I Attach the print screen using locally. http://prntscr.com/4hcjut.

Comment: And Attach the web.config http://prntscr.com/4hcn96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using Wsdl.exe

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx

This tool convert the wsdl file to Proxy Class for using this class in production in Hosting or Cloud Computing in this case Microsoft Azure.

I use the command

```
wsdl File:///C:\\servicefilefolder\FedexService.wsdl /out:C:\\projectfolder\Fedexproxy.cs
```

The tool automatically create the class called **Fedexproxy.cs**, I import to my project and use this class like a Web Reference.

Regards